# windows task scheduler event on external ip change

Tags: windows, script, ip, dhcp, event-log

UPDATE 2 : i came up with this script :

```
@echo off

nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | Find "Address:" | Find /V "208.67.222.222" >IP_1.txt
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | Find "Address:" | Find /V "208.67.222.222" >IP_2.txt

FC IP_1.txt IP_2.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto script
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto end

:script
Kill_port_forwarding_SSH.bat
Established_SSH.bat

:end
pause
```

the issue is that the script `Established_SSH.bat` would not run it would run the first one but not the second one the content of the first script is :

```
plink -ssh root@145.239.79.229 -pw 28101997 fuser -k 32400/tcp
```

I'm again looking forward to you for a way around this

---

UPDATE : now i have created two simple script that log my external ip to two different files in the same directory how could i compare the value of these and if they don't match then run my script ?

---

i'm looking for the log that windows create if it even does. When an external IP change on my computer, i'm on windows 10 pro. Basically right now the solution i've been trying is to set that :

[image: 1]

well that was supposed to monitor and give log when my external ip changes but in fact it just create a log every 10 minutes for some reason like that :

[image: 2]

so i'm looking forward to you if by any chance you can help me around with that thanks.

ps : if you need further info just ask ;) 
ps* : this event will just trigger two simple script.

Comment: Windows doesn’t know the external IP, therefore you can’t trap it for task scheduler.  You’ll need to run a script or app every X that looks up the external ip via an external service such as whatismyip.com’ API and compares it to the result last time.

Comment: I understand the principle of that, but if you could lead me to the solution it would be nice. Since the idea of scripting that sort of things is unclear, i think the biggest issue is not the tracking and comparing maybe a bit. but it's rather how do i trigger event to happen in windows task scheduler with a script as an event

Comment: See https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2014380-external-ip-address-logging

Comment: thanks for that something they don't talk about is how to input the result into a log automatically and then the whole work around comparing the result also i'm sorry to annoy you with such dull question

Comment: and my problem is I don’t know how to do it in windows.. I can do it in bash....

Comment: right now i have that '@echo
echo nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | Find "Address:" | Find /V "208.67.222.222" >C:\Users\Bastien Argaud\Desktop\log_EXT_IP.txt
pause' in a batch script but it will just not log in the result though the command itself run in a CMD will return the external ip

Comment: Google about for “log external IP changes powershell” this has been done I guarantee

Comment: okay you right sorry i'll just look around try what i see and will come back here with the result ^^ have a nice day thanks again

Comment: No problem, sometimes we just need to get pointed in the right direction to get started...

Answer (score 0):

so I found my way around i just simplified the script to that one

```
@echo off

:while 

plink -ssh root@vps_IP -pw ******** fuser -k port/tcp
plink -ssh root@vps_IP -pw ********

goto while
```

so I came to realise that the command

```
fuser -k port/tcp
```

will shut down the connection between me and the VPS so it would while the script automatically.

thanks to tyson for his guidance :)